# How to rotate parent div upon hovering on child div?

Tags: html, css

```
<style type="text/css">

#parent {
position: relative;
}

#child {
position: absolute;
}

<style>
```

html part:

```
<div id="parent">
<div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

I know I can rotate the child div by hovering over parent div.
like this:

```
#parent:hover #child {

}
```

But is there any way by which I can rotate the parent div when I hover my cursor on the child div?

Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: Won't hovering the child div also trigger the hovering of the parent div?

Comment: You can control child and siblings from parent but not parent from child. However this can be achieved with JQuery.

Comment: @NawedKhan I have seen somewhere where the guy was actually rotating the parent div from child div using pure CSS3 and html.
His code was something like this: 

.child.fast:hover + .parent, .child.fast:active + .parent {
   animation: rotator linear .5s infinite;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery

```
$("#child").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#parent").css("rotation code") //This is where you put the code for rotation.
});
```

And if you wanted the rotation to go back when mousing out

```
$("#child").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#parent").css("rotation code") //This is where you put the code for mousing out.
});
```